# Trouble to fill listview correctly

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-listview, jsoup, simpleadapter

I am getting some data from the net, which gets parsed with JSoup in a AsyncTask.

I am having trouble filling the listview correctly.

Edit1 only gets filled with empty fields (..) and the last rows have the value € 0,00.
Edit2 does not get filled at all.

```
..         edit2Text
..         edit2Text
..         edit2Text
€ 0,00     edit2Text
€ 0,00     edit2Text
```

Both Edits are in a test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<EditText
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"  
    android:id="@+id/editText1"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:text="edit1"  
    android:layout_width="200dp"
/>

<EditText
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_width="110dp"  
    android:id="@+id/editText2"  
    android:text="edit2" 
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The listview should look like this:

```
Einddatum contract: 08-10-2012
Prijs per maand: € 38,50 /mnd
...
```

I catch map and map1 to see if they are filled correctly and they do, what i am doing wrong?

```
10-22 10:35:21.698: I/System.out(8132): Hashmap: {col_1=Einddatum contract:}
10-22 10:35:21.698: I/System.out(8132): Hashmap: {col_1=Prijs per maand:}
10-22 10:35:21.698: I/System.out(8132): Hashmap: {col_1=Einddatum contract:}
10-22 10:35:21.698: I/System.out(8132): Hashmap: {col_1=Prijs per maand:}
10-22 10:35:21.698: I/System.out(8132): Hashmap: {col_1=Nieuw beltegoed:}
10-22 10:35:21.698: I/System.out(8132): Hashmap: {col_1=Tegoed vorige periode:}
10-22 10:35:21.708: I/System.out(8132): Hashmap: {col_1=Tegoed tot 09-11-2011:}
10-22 10:35:21.708: I/System.out(8132): Hashmap: {col_1=}
10-22 10:35:21.708: I/System.out(8132): Hashmap: {col_1=Verbruik sinds nieuw tegoed:}
10-22 10:35:21.708: I/System.out(8132): Hashmap: {col_1=Ongebruikt tegoed:}
10-22 10:35:21.708: I/System.out(8132): Hashmap: {col_1=Verbruik boven bundel:}
10-22 10:35:21.708: I/System.out(8132): Hashmap: {col_1=Verbruik dat niet in de bundel zit*:}
10-22 10:35:21.718: I/System.out(8132): Hashmap1: {col_2=08-10-2012}
10-22 10:35:21.718: I/System.out(8132): Hashmap1: {col_2=€ 38,50 /mnd}
10-22 10:35:21.718: I/System.out(8132): Hashmap1: {col_2=08-10-2012}
10-22 10:35:21.718: I/System.out(8132): Hashmap1: {col_2=€ 38,50 /mnd}
10-22 10:35:21.718: I/System.out(8132): Hashmap1: {col_2=€ 54,64}
10-22 10:35:21.718: I/System.out(8132): Hashmap1: {col_2=€ 17,28}
10-22 10:35:21.718: I/System.out(8132): Hashmap1: {col_2=€ 71,92}
10-22 10:35:21.718: I/System.out(8132): Hashmap1: {col_2=}
10-22 10:35:21.718: I/System.out(8132): Hashmap1: {col_2=€ 5,32}
10-22 10:35:21.718: I/System.out(8132): Hashmap1: {col_2=€ 66,60}
10-22 10:35:21.718: I/System.out(8132): Hashmap1: {col_2=€ 0,00}
10-22 10:35:21.718: I/System.out(8132): Hashmap1: {col_2=€ 0,00}
```

My code:

```
@Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
        // create the grid item mapping
        ListView kp = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.kpn);

        String[] from = new String[] {"col_1", "col_2"};
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.editText1, R.id.editText1 };

        List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();


        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(kpn);
        Elements tdsFromSecondColumn = doc.select("table.personaltable td:eq(0)");
        Elements tdsFromSecondColumn1 = doc.select("table.personaltable td:eq(1)"); 

        for (Element tdFromSecondColumn : tdsFromSecondColumn) {
            map.put("col_1", tdFromSecondColumn.text()); 
            fillMaps.add(map);

            System.out.println("Hashmap: " + map);

        } 
        for (Element tdFromSecondColumn1 : tdsFromSecondColumn1) {
            map1.put("col_2", tdFromSecondColumn1.text());
            fillMaps.add(map1);

            System.out.println("Hashmap1: " + map1);
        }

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AndroidLogin.this, fillMaps, R.layout.test, from, to); 
        kp.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: See this code line properly, does it same in yours - int[] to = new int[] { R.id.editText1, R.id.editText2 };

Comment: look at my edited answer, and try this code, currently in my mind I have only this idea to make new list from other two and pass it to adapter. And if its correct then please accept as correct answer and upvote it for you and other user.

Comment: Try below code, I modified it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
@Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
        // create the grid item mapping
        ListView kp = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.kpn);

        String[] from = new String[] {"col_1", "col_2"};
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.editText1, R.id.editText2 };

        List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
          List<HashMap<String, String>> fill_Maps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

 HashMap<String, String> map;
 HashMap<String, String> map1;


        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(kpn);
        Elements tdsFromSecondColumn = doc.select("table.personaltable td:eq(0)");
        Elements tdsFromSecondColumn1 = doc.select("table.personaltable td:eq(1)"); 

        for (Element tdFromSecondColumn : tdsFromSecondColumn) {

                  map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                  map.put("col_1", tdFromSecondColumn.text()); 
            fillMaps.add(map);

            System.out.println("Hashmap: " + map);

        } 
        for (Element tdFromSecondColumn1 : tdsFromSecondColumn1) {
                           map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();                                      map1.put("col_2", tdFromSecondColumn1.text());
            fillMaps1.add(map1);

            System.out.println("Hashmap1: " + map1);
        }

                        for (int i=0;i<fillMap.size();i++) {

               fill_Map.add(fillMap.get(i));
               fill_Map.add(fillMap1.get(i));
}
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AndroidLogin.this, fill_Map, R.layout.test, from, to); 
        kp.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And let me know what happen..

Comment: Hi, thx for replying.
I tried youre code but now the edit1 gets filled with the map1 values, i.a 08-10-2012, € 38,50 /mnd etc.
Edit2 remains empty..

Comment: See this code line properly, does it same in yours - int[] to = new int[] { R.id.editText1, R.id.editText2 };

Comment: Hmmm, ok tried that.
We`re almost there now edit1 gets filled correctly with "map" items, edit2 also gets filled with "map1" items but they are not matched next to each other.
The map1 items in edit2 start where map items in edit1 end.

Comment: Ok, its because of, fillMaps.add(map); and fillMaps.add(map1); here you fill list first by map item then map1 item, so do it like fillMaps.add(map); fillMaps.add(map1); in one for loop so your list contain alternative value like, map,map1,map,map1......

Comment: Ok, makes sence but i as far as i can see i can not combine the two for loops.
Can you give an example of what you mean?
Thx.

Comment: are both for loop have same size itteration? means both loop have same size?

Comment: As fars as i know yes, they itterate through the xml file and pick the values included in the <td> tags.
That is the data which i need.

Comment: look at my edited answer, and try this code, currently in my mind I have only this idea to make new list from other two and pass it to adapter. And if its correct then please accept as correct answer and upvote it for you and other user.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your efforts.
I accepted your answer but the edit1 and edit2 text are still not matched next to each other.
I now get:
Einddatum contract:  edit2 empty
edit1 empty: 08-10-2012
Hmmm this a tough one.

Comment: you have to do just make a list with map item,map1 item,map item,map1 item.. and pass it in adapter, so you achieve what you want. Thanks.